# How do I restart qmail?

Tags: ssh, qmail

I have a VPS and root ssh access. I'm sure I've restarted Qmail before via SSH but can't figure out how.

I've tried to run `/etc/init.d/qmail restart` but all I get is `-bash: /etc/init.d/qmail: No such file or directory`.

I've also run:

```
ps ax | grep qmail-send
12035 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep qmail-send
```

I'd greatly appreciate direction on how to do this, and also what the process would be for figuring this sort of thing out in the future would be.

Many thanks. 
Stevie

Edit:
While I use Plesk, I've also got WebMin installed, and it tells me that the command to start Qmail is: "Just run rc script", while the command to stop it is: "Just kill qmail-send".  I'm still a little lost though.

Comment: This is old but for those who stumble here, qmail is typically started via /service/qmail and restarted by running svc -t /service/qmail which is effectively the same thing as `killall qmail-start`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, my 1&1 Plesk driven VPS is crap... it's using Postfix rather than Qmail, which explains why it cannot be restarted.

This is blurred by the fact that my mailbox configurations are automatically stored in a folder called /var/qmail/mailnames

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my answer would still be actual for you, but anyway -

if on Plesk, you can check whether Qmail is installed with

```
rpm -q psa-qmail
```

yet lack of `/etc/init.d/qmail` script definitely indicates there are no Qmail installed. At some point it was declared that [Postfix is replacing Qmail](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/lifecycle/) for Plesk.

Postfix can be restarted like any other Linux service

```
/etc/init.d/postfix {start|stop|restart|reload|abort|flush|check|status|condrestart}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on location of installation

```
/etc/init.d/qmail restart (will probably not work)
```

So try the following commands

```
sudo pkill -9 qmail
/var/qmail/bin/qmail-start
```